# Parsing XML file more than once and merging the results together

Tags: xml, perl, filter, merge, libxml2

I have a subroutine that parses 2 XMLs, one is the original log data, the other is a filter. I want to remove everything from the log.xml that is not found in one of the filters.

Here is an example of my log file:

```
<log>
  <message>
    <type>warning</type>
    <from>cody</from>
    <content>cant use XML::Merge</content>
  </message>
  <message>
    <type>error</type>
    <from>cody</from>
    <content>some text here</content>
  </message>
  <message>
    <type>warning</type>
    <from>charlie</from>
    <content>ruff</content>
  </message>
  <message>
    <type>error</type>
    <from>cody</from>
    <content>an error</content>
  </message>
</log>
```

with a filter.xml that looks like:

```
<filters>
  <filter>
    <type>warning</type>
    <content>XML::Merge</content>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <type>error</type>
  </filter>
</filters>
```

This should result in all warnings containing the content "XML::Merge" to be retained and ALL errors as well. My attempt has been to make a first pass with the first filter, which results in all other message nodes being chopped, so I get no errors in the resulting XML file. The next filter then chops off the ones that were supposed to remain from the first filter. Here is my code, which works well if only one filter is in the filter.xml.

```
sub include {
  my $filterParser = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($filterXML);
  my $logParser = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($xml);

  foreach my $filter ( $filterParser->findnodes('/filters/filter') ) {
    foreach my $msg ( $logParser->findnodes('/log/message') ) {
        foreach my $msgNode ($msg->childNodes) {
            foreach my $filterNode ($filter->childNodes) {
                if ($msgNode->localName eq $filterNode->localName) {
                    my $m = $msgNode->textContent;
                    my $f = $filterNode->textContent;
                    if (index($m, $f) == -1) {
                        $msg->parentNode->removeChild($msg);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
  } 
  $logParser->toFile($xml);
}
```

I understand why it outputs a blank doc with more than one filter, but need help on getting the first pass saved somewhere, then use the original XML to make a pass with the second filter, and so on, until no filters are left and then merge everything into one XML, without duplicate messages.

Comment: I'd probably write an XSLT file that converts your filter file into an XSLT file that performs the filtering.

Comment: @reinierpost yes, I kind of wish I had gone that route, but was already heavy into LibXML and didn't want to start to learn something else. It seemed best to stick with what I was getting used to.

Comment: @reinierpost also, isn't that adding an extra step? Converting the filter.xml to XSLT and then performing the filter? I think the solution I came to may not be best for large log.xml files (haven't tried any yet), but I think I can speed it up with some more flags to break the loops when a node has been marked as kept for sure.

Comment: The advantage is that it is all in XSLT, which is (even) more portable than a Perl solution, and it was also designed to be fast, but I have never personally put that to a test.

Comment: When using Perl I'd use the solution you've chosen (XML::LibXML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I probably titled this question poorly, but hopefully this quention and answer will help someone else some day. Anyway I've accomplished my goal with some brute force... I ended up doing a pass for each filter, and added the nodes that I want to keep to a list (I needed a flag because some filters have more than one single criteria). After all filters have been processed on all messages, I then loop through the log.xml and look for each node saved in my list. If the node from the log.xml doesn't match any in the list, I remove it from the tree.

```
sub include {
  my $filterParser = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($filterXML);
  my $logParser = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($xml);

  my $remove = true;
  my @nodes;

  foreach my $msg ( $logParser->findnodes('/TdsMainLog/message') ) {
    foreach my $filter ( $filterParser->findnodes('/filters/filter') ) {
        foreach my $msgNode ($msg->childNodes) {
            foreach my $filterNode ($filter->childNodes) {  
                if ($msgNode->localName eq $filterNode->localName) {
                    my $m = $msgNode->textContent;
                    my $f = $filterNode->textContent;
                    if ( index($m, $f) != -1 ) {
                        #mark for keeping
                        $remove = false;
                    } 
                    else { $remove = true; } #else unmark
                }
            }
        }
        if ($remove eq false) { push (@nodes, $msg); }
        $remove = true;
    }
  }

  foreach my $msg ( $logParser->findnodes('/TdsMainLog/message') ) {
    $remove = true;
    foreach my $node (@nodes) {
        if ($msg->isSameNode($node)) {
            $remove = false;
        }
    }
    if ($remove eq true) { $msg->parentNode->removeChild($msg); }
  }
    $logParser->toFile($xml);
  }
```